# PHPUnit testing an exception flow of execution

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, private-members, test-coverage

I guess this is a common problem but I am unable to decide how to solve this.

I have a public function that has 4 catch blocks. Inside each catch block one of the private methods is called as below

```
public function updateInformation(){

 try{
    .....
  }catch(Zend_Http_Client_Exception $e){
    $this->somePrivateMethod1();
  }catch(Zend_Service_Exception $e){
    $this->somePrivateMethod2();
  }catch(UnexpectedValueException $e){
    $this->somePrivateMethod3();
  }catch(Exception $e){
    $this->somePrivateMethod4();
  }

}
```

I am writing test case to test the `updateInformation()` function. I would like to test the exception blocks too which would let me test the private methods(too). How do I achieve this? Because of this the code coverage is also gone for a toss.

Comment: I have provided an answer that outlines the basics of what you need to do.  But more information about the class you are testing would help to provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one of your dependencies throw the Exception so that your code will catch it.

http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest8.php

```
public function testThrowExceptionStub()
    {
        // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
        $stub = $this->getMock('SomeClass');

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->method('doSomething')
             ->will($this->throwException(new Exception));

        $sut = new Class($stub);

        $sut->updateInformation();

        //DO MORE ASSERTIONS ABOUT BEHAVIOR IN PRIVATE METHODS

    }
}
```

I am assuming that there is something in the `try` block that will need to be mocked.  If there isn't then you set the class up so that the conditions are met such that the exceptions will be thrown.